# crc32 with given parameters

Tags: crc32

I have to create a crc32 sum over a file.
But there are some dependencies:

```
crc32 with the polynom 0x04C11DB7
Init of the crc with 0xffffffff 
and a final XOR with 0xffffffff
```

How can i get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the standard CRC-32 used by zip, gzip, zlib, etc.  You can simply use the `crc32()` function in [zlib](http://zlib.net/).